# Binary to Decimal Conversion in C - Input Size Issue

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I have to write a C program for one of my classes that converts a given binary number to decimal. My program works for smaller inputs, but not for larger ones. I believe this may be due to the conversion specifier I am using for scanf() but I am not positive. My code is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long inputNum = 0;
    int currentBinary = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float decimalNumber = 0;

    printf( "Input a binary number: " );
    scanf( "%lu", &inputNum );

    while (inputNum != 0)
    {
        currentBinary = inputNum % 10;
        inputNum = inputNum / 10;

        printf("%d\t%d\n", currentBinary, inputNum);

        decimalNumber += currentBinary * pow(2, count);

        ++count;
    }

    printf("Decimal conversion: %.0f", decimalNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Running with a small binary number:

```
Input a binary number: 1011
1       101
1       10
0       1
1       0
Decimal conversion: 11
```

Running with a larger binary number:

```
Input a binary number: 1000100011111000
2       399133551
1       39913355
5       3991335
5       399133
3       39913
3       3991
1       399
9       39
9       3
3       0
Decimal conversion: 5264
```

Comment: Read the input as a string and that might help you

Comment: char at a time is one way to do this without the limitation of trying to stuff a binary string into a integer-type. [see example](http://ideone.com/X349Fn).

Comment: @WhozCraig Nice, but recommend `sizeof(inputNum) * CHAR_BIT + /* not 1 */ 2` for the `"\n\0"`.

Comment: I don't know about the tools that you may use, but C knows how to read binary numbers without problems. Read the string with `fgets` and then parse it with `strtoull` where you give it a `2` for the `base` parameter.

Comment: @chux heh. teaches me to slap code on ideone. yeah, you're right =P

Answer (score 2):

"1000100011111000" is a 20 digit number.  Certainly `unsigned long` is too small on your platform.

`unsigned long` is good - up to at least 10 digits.<sup>1</sup>
`unsigned long long`  is better - up to at least 20 digits.<sup>1</sup>

To get past that:
Below is an any size conversion by reading 1 `char` at a time and forming an unbounded string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Double the decimal form of string: "512" --> "1024"
char *sdouble(char *s, size_t *len, int carry) {
  size_t i = *len;
  while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    int sum = (s[i] - '0')*2 + carry;
    s[i] = sum%10 + '0';
    carry = sum/10;
  }
  if (carry) {
    (*len)++;
    s = realloc(s, *len + 1);  // TBD OOM check
    memmove(&s[1], s, *len);
    s[0] = carry + '0';
  }
  return s;
}

int main(void) {

  int ch;
  size_t len = 1;
  char *s = malloc(len + 1); // TBD OOM check
  strcpy(s, "0");
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) >= '0' && ch <= '1') {
    s = sdouble(s, &len, ch - '0');
  }
  puts(s);
  free(s);
  return 0;
}
```

> 100 digits
> 1111111111000000000011111111110000000000111111111100000000001111111111000000000011111111110000000000
>
> 1266413867935323811836706421760

---

<sup>1</sup> When the lead digit is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this for a large number `inputNum`

```
currentBinary = inputNum % 10;
```

its top portion gets "sliced off" on conversion to `int`. If you would like to stay within the bounds of an `unsigned long`, switch `currentBinary` to `unsigned long` as well, and use an unsigned long format specifier in `printf`. Moreover, `unsigned long` may not be sufficiently large on many platforms, so you need to use `unsigned long long`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/7jkeDf)

Better yet, switch to reading the input in a string, validating it to be zeros and ones (you have to do that anyway) and do the conversion in a cleaner character-by-character way. This would let you go beyond the 64-bit of 19 binary digits to have a full-scale `int` input.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned long` [supports a maximum number of 4294967295](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/), which means in the process of `scanf( "%lu", &inputNum );` you've sliced the decimal number `1000100011111000` to a 32-bit unsigned long number.

I think `scanf` inputNum to a string would help a lot. In the `while` loop condition check if the string is empty now, and in the loop body get the last char of the string, detect if it's an `'1'` of a `'0'`, and then calculate the binary number using this info.

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked with writing a binary to decimal converted with taking larger binary inputs, but using embedded C programming in which we are not allowed to use library functions such as strlen. I found a simpler way to write this conversion tool using C, with both strlen, and also sizeof, as shown in the code below. Hope this helps. As you can see, strlen is commented out but either approach works fine. Sizeof just accounts for the 0 elecment in the array and that is why sizeof (number) -1 is used. Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char number[] = "100111111111111111111111";
int binToDec(char *);

int main()
{
    printf("Output: %d", binToDec(&number));
}

int binToDec(char *n)
{
    char *num = n;
    int decimal_value = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int i;

    int len = sizeof(number)-1;
    //int len = strlen(number);
    for (i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (num[i] == '1')
            decimal_value += base;
        base = base * 2;
    }

    return decimal_value;
}
```